# How to prevent or avoid running update and delete statements without where clauses in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

How to prevent or avoid running update or delete statements without where clauses in PostgreSQL?

Same as **SQL_SAFE_UPDATES** statement in MySQL is needed for PostgreSQL.

*For example:*

```
UPDATE table_name SET active=1; -- Prevent this statement or throw error message.
UPDATE table_name SET active=1 WHERE id=1; -- This is allowed
```

> My company database has many users with insert and update privilege any one of the users do that unsafe update. 
>   In this secoario how to handle this. 
>   Any idea can write trigger or any extension to handle the unsafe update in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

I have switched off autocommits to avoid these errors. So I always have a transaction that I can roll back. All you have to do is modify `.psqlrc`:

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
\echo AUTOCOMMIT = :AUTOCOMMIT
\set PROMPT1 '%[%033[32m%]%/%[%033[0m%]%R%[%033[1;32;40m%]%x%[%033[0m%]%# '
\set PROMPT2 '%[%033[32m%]%/%[%033[0m%]%R%[%033[1;32;40m%]%x%[%033[0m%]%# '
\set PROMPT3 '>> '
```

You don't have to insert the `PROMPT` statements. But they are helpful because they change the `psql` prompt to show the transaction status.

Another advantage of this approach is that it gives you a chance to prevent any erroneous changes.

Example (`psql`):

```
database=# SELECT * FROM my_table; -- implicit start transaction; see prompt
-- output result
database*# UPDATE my_table SET my_column = 1; -- missed where clause
UPDATE 525125 -- Oh, no!
database*# ROLLBACK; -- Puh! revert wrong changes
ROLLBACK
database=#   -- I'm completely operational and all of my circuits working perfectly
```

Comment: In a live production database, how we use rollback. If we user rollback data loss may occur know.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: @SrinivasanE: if that extension does what you want, then why don't you just install it?

Comment: When I try to install that extension, I got this message "ERROR: extension 'safeupate' not found"

Comment: You have to compile and install the extension on your server as described. After that you can load it.

Comment: No way to have it autocommit on SELECT? It feels weird that this starts a transaction when you're not already in one. Usually I only query the database, so usually I'd like autocommit on. It's only to prevent where-less updates I need to guard against, since I just did one (thankfully quick enough on the CTRL+C to stop the disaster).

Answer (score 2):

There actually was [a discussion on the hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20160721045746.GA25043%40fetter.org) about this very feature. It had a mixed reception, but might have been accepted if the author had persisted.

As it is, the best you can do is a statement level trigger that bleats if you modify too many rows:

```
CREATE TABLE deleteme
AS SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, 1000) AS i;

CREATE FUNCTION stop_mass_deletes() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF (SELECT count(*) FROM OLD) > TG_ARGV[0]::bigint THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'must not modify more than % rows', TG_ARGV[0];
   END IF;
   RETURN NULL;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER stop_mass_deletes AFTER DELETE ON deleteme
   REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE FUNCTION stop_mass_deletes(10);

DELETE FROM deleteme WHERE i < 100;
ERROR:  must not modify more than 10 rows
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function stop_mass_deletes() line 1 at RAISE

DELETE FROM deleteme WHERE i < 10;
DELETE 9
```

This will have a certain performance impact on deletes.

This works from v10 on, when transition tables were introduced.

Comment: **When I execute this trigger,**
`CREATE TRIGGER stop_mass_deletes AFTER DELETE ON deleteme
 REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old FOR EACH STATEMENT
 EXECUTE FUNCTION stop_mass_deletes(10)`
**I got below error message:**
`syntax error at or near "REFERENCING"
LINE 2: REFERENCING old table as test FOR EACH STATEMENT`
**I can't find any error here. Kindly help me to fix this**.

Comment: Then you must be using an old version (9.6 or older).

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford making it a little less convinient for your users, you might try revoking UPDATE privilege for all "standard" users and creating a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update(table_name, col_name, new_value, condition) RETURNS void
/*
Check if condition is acceptable, create and run UPDATE statement
*/
LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
```

Because of `SECURITY DEFINER` this way your users will be able to UPDATE despite not having UPDATE privilege.

I'm not sure if this is a good approach, but this way you can force as strict UPDATE (or anything else) requirements as you wish.

Of course the more complicated UPDATES are required, the more complicated has to be your procedure, but if this is mostly just about updating single row by ID (as in your example) this might be worth a try.